# Shell script that starts a process, starts another process, then kills the first process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell-script

Let's imagine I have a `client` and a `server` on the same machine, and I'd like to script some interaction between them.

I would really like a shell script to -

1. Start `server`
2. Put `server` in the background
3. Start `client`
4. (wait for `client` to do whatever it does)
5. Stop `server`

I can do most of that already, like this -

```
./server &
./client
```

But that leaves `server` running after the script finishes which, apart from anything else, is very untidy.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bash job control:

```
#!/bin/bash

./server &
./client
kill %1
```

Be sure to put the `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script so that bash is used to execute the script (I'm not sure if job control is supported in sh, please correct me if it does).

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result with standard POSIX sh. In sh, when you spawn a process in the background using '&', the PID of the process is stored in the special variable $!. So:

```
#!/bin/sh
./server &
./client
kill $!
```

For more complex situations you might want to save the pid:

```
#!/bin/sh
./server &
serverpid=$!
# ... lots of other stuff
kill $serverpid
```