# Bash scripts executed together don't kill background processes

Tags: macos, bash, sh

I have a number of shell scripts that work very similarly to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/310983/shell-script-that-starts-a-process-starts-another-process-then-kills-the-first).  Each script fires up a few background tasks, remembers their PIDs with `$!`, does some testing, and then kills the background processes.

My problem is that I want to run a large number of these kind of scripts.  If I run them manually one by one, they work fine: `ps -a` shows that the background processes were killed properly.

```
$ ./test_1.sh
$ ./test_2.sh
```

However, if I run them both in one command like so:

```
$ ./test_1.sh; ./test_2.sh
```

the background process started by `test_1.sh` fails to die by the time `test_2.sh` starts.  This leaves a port tied up that `test_2.sh` needs to bind to.  So even though `test_1.sh` issues the correct `kill` commands, `test_2.sh` crashes if it's execute right after `test_1.sh`.

If I insert a delay between the scripts, there is no problem:

```
$ ./test_1.sh; sleep 1; ./test_2.sh
```

Presumably, then, there is a delay between when `kill` is issued and when the process actually dies and releases the port.

My questions are:

1. What's going on? Is this platform specific?  I'm on Mac OS X.  But this doesn't appear to have been a problem for the people who originally wrote the scripts on Linux.
2. Is there a better way to ensure that the background processes have been killed, without using `sleep` between scripts?

---

---

For completeness, this is what one of the test scripts looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "starting up server 1(parent)..."
$JAVA siena.StartServer -port 7000 &
server1=$!
sleep 2

echo "starting up server 2(the first child)..."
$JAVA siena.StartServer -port 2000 -master senp://:7000 > outputs/test.out2 &
server2=$!

echo "starting up server 3(the second child)..."
$JAVA siena.StartServer -port 3000 -master senp://:7000 > outputs/test.out2 &
server3=$!

sleep 5

kill $server1
kill $server2
kill $server3
```

Comment: Well, the command `kill` only sends signals to the process, it does not really verify that the process has been killed. Usually, a `SIGTERM` is sent, which the process can even ignore. Even if it complies with it, it may still do some housecleaning before it actually terminates. A quicker way would be to kill with signal `SIGKILL`, however, the process will not have a chance to e.g. flush buffers and it still will NOT be truely instantaneous. I guess a safer way would be to poll a `/proc/<PROCID>` path if that is available on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the processes to die. Usually it is a good idea to wait between a SIGTERM and a SIGKILL.

It is considered rude manners (and in my opinion rather unprofessional) to SIGKILL processes without having asked a gracefully shutdown before.  Not only can this create inconsistencies but it also hides faulty shutdown procedures (programs failing to close in a certain time when requested to).

I would use something like:

```
# Launch your processes...
DEADLINE=1   #seconds to wait
kill $server1 $server2 $server3
sleep $DEADLINE 
if kill -KILL $server1 $server2 $server3
then 
  echo "Warning: at least one process had not finished in $DEADLINE seconds" >&2
  sleep 1   ## Wait for these just-killed processes to actually die and free their ports
fi
```

Another approach would be to find a free port from inside the server itself (binding without a port and somehow communicating outside the assigned port).  This would allow for parallel testing.  You could write the port number to a file specified in the command line (instead of the port, you would pass the file name), thus changing `-port 7000` to something like `-port auto -port-file test-port.txt` and then waiting for this file to appear and then `-master senp://:$(cat test-port.txt)`.

Another idea would be to automatically find out, based on information of `netstat -ntl`, whether your required ports are free or not.  Then, you could choose either to wait or to specify a fresh set of available ports.  Race conditions might well happen between the time you see a port free and the moment you actually bind, especially if your allocation algorithm is determinist and repeatable (such as using the first available port starting at 40000).  Letting the operating system choose a free port itself is by far more robust.